# XP clients can't see first two folders on file server

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

XP machines are having this weird behavior with our new file severs. On a few subfolders, the client machines can't see all the files and folders. **The first two folders, alphabetically, will be missing.** If i add another folder that goes before the missing ones, one missing folder appears but the new one is now missing.

If I know the name of the folder, I can access it, but in the parent folder it doesn't get listed. I've ruled out security permission. **The only thing in common is the XP clients have the issue** and the window7 machines do not.

All servers and clients are fully patched and have the service packs installed.

Dell Equilogic 
Servers Windows Storage Server 2008

I'm going crazy here.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Can you post videos here?

Comment: You can post a link to YouTube if you need to.